# background image doesn't show in span tag

Tags: html, css

I have the current situation.I have set the width for span, the image still not showing up.

```
<header>
        <img src="img/hamburger_menu.jpg" alt="hamburger menu">
        <span>PHOTOSTORY</span>
        <span>780-978-5975</span>
</header>
header span:nth-child(3){
margin-left:322px;
background-image: url("img/phone_bg.jpg") no-repeat top left;
height:38px;
width:204px;
}
```

Comment: try adding `display: inline-block;` so that the span will respect the height.

Comment: did you wrap those css in `<style>` tag?

Comment: I tried that before, it's not working

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set attributes "no-repeat top left" if you declare background-image. In `background-image` you must set only link to your image. 
For repeat attribute use `background-repeat` and for "top left" use `background-position`.
I recommend to use shortcut `background: url("img/phone_bg.jpg") no-repeat top left;`